# need help creating a vector and using it to play my playnote function

Tags: matlab, function, vector

i have created a playNote Function with 1 input and no output,

i want to create a vector of four frequencies 330, 440, 554, 659 but i don't know how to

then i want to test the playNote Function with the vector of four frequencies that is created

```
%%
function playFreq(x)
switch x
    case 1 
        Freq = 659;
    case 2
        Freq = 554;
    case 3
        Freq = 440;
    case 4
        Freq = 330;
    case 5
        Freq = 220;
end
    Fs = 8000; % speed
    ts = 1./Fs;
    t = [0:ts:0.5]; % 0.5 sec
    y = sin(Freq.* 2.* pi.* t);
    sound(y,Fs);
    pause(.5);

end
```

Comment: Do you want to play a combination of your 4 frequencies?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, please explain what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly, you want to play several frequencies at the same time.

You can rewrite your function to take a vector as the input:

```
function playFreq(Freq)
    Fs = 8000; % speed
    ts = 1./Fs;
    t = 0:ts:0.5; % 0.5 sec
    y = zeros(size(t));
    for i = 1:length(Freq)
        y = y + sin(Freq(i).* 2.* pi.* t);
    end
    y = y/max(y(:));
    sound(y,Fs);
    pause(.5);
end
```

Then you can call your function by defining a vector of frequency:

```
Freq = [330, 440, 554, 659];
playFreq(Freq);
```

Comment: You forgot to normalize: `y=y/max(y(:))` to dynamically scale to max amplitude or `y=y/numel(Freq)` to have a fixed scaling factor.

Comment: That the reason why it sounded saturated! Thanks for that